# Is it possible to run a MySQL query based on the result of an alias?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN col1_alias='' THEN 'empty value'
  ELSE 'has value' 
  END AS result, 
  (/* a complicated mysql SELECT statement */) AS col_alias
FROM my_table;
```

The above MySQL query gives me `Unknown column 'col_alias' in 'field list'` error.

Is it possible to generate the `result` column based on the value of `col`?

I don't want to write the complicated MySQL SELECT statement for the second time.

============================== EDIT ================================

Sorry, I forgot to mention that my real situation is more complicated than the query pasted above.

My real query contains `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
  my_table.id AS id,
  CASE 
    WHEN col1_alias='' THEN 'empty value'
    ELSE 'has value' 
    END AS result, 
    (/* a complicated mysql SELECT statement */) AS col_alias,
    another_table.name AS name
  FROM my_table 
    LEFT JOIN another_table
  ON 
    `my_table`.`id` = `another_table`.`id`
  GROUP BY
  `another_table`.`name`;
```

Is it possible to avoid `Unknown column 'col_alias' in 'field list'` in this situation?

I think I might have to write part of the query results to a temporary table. Then write a second query that runs against the original and the temporary table.

However, I still wish that I can use only one query to accomplish the goal.

Comment: Does it really need to be done in SQL. I'd solve it in the view layer.

Comment: BTW: `SELECT left_table.id .. FROM left_table LEFT JOIN right_table .. GROUP BY right_table.name` looks quite strange.

Comment: This MySQL query is used to generate a business data report of our company. It looks like a plate of spaghetti. No one in my company likes to touch it. But now there's a bug inside the query. And I have to fix that bug.

Comment: A bug? The whole query is a bug. Chuck it away and start over.